# How to bind function to Async.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, bind, async.js

I have the following block of code that gets called via an internal API.
I'm trying to use async.js to do some flow control here but as you'll see below we lose context to "R". I also lose content to "this" which is addressed with the ugly but simplest solution of "self = this".

So my question is how do i bind R to the async.series?  I'm syntactically confused on how to do this.

```
"condition": function(R) {
    var self = this;
    async.series([
        function(R){
            R.check(List.redisTables.List.negEmail, self.customer.email)
        },
        function(R) {
            R.when(self.virtual.negEmail === "true")
        }
    ])

}, 
 ///more code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easier to test similar example:

```js
  function getFunctions(asd) {
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(function(asd) {
      console.log(asd)
    }.bind(this, asd));
    return arr
  };
  var funcs = getFunctions("yay");
  for (var i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
    funcs[i]()
  }
```

So basically, you need to bind the R to the function as argument. In your case, it would be:

```
async.series([
    function(R){
        R.check(List.redisTables.List.negEmail, this.customer.email)
    }.bind(this,R),
    function(R) {
        R.when(this.virtual.negEmail === "true")
    }.bind(this,R)
])
```

Comment: Yep, that works.Thanks.  This can get kind of ugly when the number of functions in the series grows. I suppose I can create a wrapper (for loop) to apply the bind to each function.  Is there some better option you're aware of?

Comment: @Cyph just add the functions to an array, iterate the array, do `array[i].bind(this, R)` and then `async.series(array)`